# How to dynamically reduce all fonts to 50% using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a web page with various font sizes all assigned using px sizes. I want to be able to dynamically change all the font sizes to 50% of it's original size using JavaScript. I tried using a CSS rule but realized that you cannot change font sizes that have an px defined size.

Comment: @Hless that won't override styles with an explicit size > http://jsfiddle.net/F9yC7/2/

Comment: Thought it did, but I totally forgot that I'm working with `em` units on my current project. Gah, so much to process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    var f_size = getComputedStyle(elems[i]).fontSize;
    var numb   = f_size.replace(/\D/g,''); // the number
    var val    = f_size.replace(/\d/g,''); // px

    elems[i].style.fontSize = (+numb / 2) + val;    
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9yC7/9/)

Comment: This is the closest so far. Only thing I'd note is, I'm not sure if doing it this way might result in the font size changing for descendants specified in ems by the time you get to them; have you tested this? :)

Comment: @JordanGray - Nope, haven't tested that, but I suppose it could do that, but iterating from the deepest nested element and up through parents would be overly complicated for this answer, but that would be the solution if that's an issue.

Comment: As a sidenote, the computedStyle should always be a pixel value, I don't think it ever returns em or % ?

Comment: @JordanGray - added a fiddle, doesn't seem to be an issue ?

Comment: @Nagarjun - No problem, note that `querySelectorAll` isn't supported in IE7 and below, it that's an issue

Comment: BTW—for anyone else with similar doubts, [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9PLz7/). The trick that I missed is that because this goes through the matched DOM elements backwards, it always starts with the deepest children in a node before reaching the node itself. (You can verify this by changing the loop to go forwards.) Good job!

Comment: @JordanGray - That's just good habits I suppose. `querySelectorAll` is not live, so iterating backwards isn't usually needed, but on live nodelists, such as when using `getElementsByClassName` etc, one should always iterate backwards as changing a live nodelist in a loop will cause lots of headaches when iterated the normal way, been there and done that, so now I always go in reverse, and in this case the reversed iteration actually has the unintended benefit of changing the nested elements before the parent changes the computedStyle of the child. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple if jQuery is an option:

```
$('*').css('font-size', function() {  
    return (parseInt($(this).css('font-size')) * 0.5);
});
```

Please see the [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F9yC7/1/).

Answer (score 0):

px fonts could be set 50%, but it is not suggested to do it with just js.

The most commonly plan is you define the base font-size in your css, usually on body, for example:

```
body { font-size: 14px; }
```

and all other elments defined with em; for example:

```
h2.titleExample {
    font-size: 2em; //this will be 28px for the base font-size is 14px
}
```

and you may change the base font-size using javascript,(jquery example)

```
function switchFS(fontSize) {
    $('body').css('font-size': fontSize);
};
switchFS('20px'); //or even swtichFS('2em');
```

or you just define all your styles in the css file. with a class for font-size to switch font-size; for example:

```
//css class
.font-normal { font-size: 14px; }
.font-large { font-size: 16px; }
.font-exlarge { font-size: 18px }
//js file
function switchFS(cls) {
    $('body').removeClass().addClass(cls);  
};
switchFS('font-large'); //call to get larger
```

Comment: defining pixel with 'em' is not suggested as it result in unexpected behaviour of font-sizes with changing resolution. Rather, try defining base-font size (eg, in body) in pixel and rest of them in percent.